# How to trigger a lambda from kinesis data firehose logging?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm attempting to invoke a lambda from a put-record event to Kinesis Data Firehose (KDF) delivery stream via a Cloudwatch event rule. I want the lambda to fire after a [PutRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) event has been detected from the logging.

The problem is, I can't actually find any logging from KDF that is informative as to when a PutRecord event has occurred. From reading [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch-logs.html), it would appear only error logging is delivered to Cloudwatch.

If this is the case, how is one able to detect when a PutRecord action has been taken by KDF and invoke a lambda accordingly? I have looked into a [KDF Data Transformation lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html), but this isn't detecting any change from the logging KDF is emitting, it's just transforming each and every data point ingested into the stream!

Any suggestions or advice as to how to observe PutRecord actions from KDF via logs would be greatly appreciated.